# Particular solution of $z=x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}+\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the partial differential equation $z=x \frac {\partial z} {\partial x} +y \frac {\partial z} {\partial y} +\frac {\partial z} {\partial x} \frac {\partial z} {\partial y} $ then
(A) the particular solution passing through $x=0$ and $z=y^2$ is $\left(\frac x4-y\right) ^2$
(B) the particular solution passing through $x=0$ and $z=y^2$ is $\left(\frac x4+y\right) ^2$
**Try**
After applying charpits auxiliary equation the complete integral I get is $z=ax+by+ab$ where $a, b$ are arbitrary constants.
To find particular integral I need to find particular value for $a$ and $b$. Here I am stucked. How to find $a$ and $b$? Please help.

Comment: Is anyone awake?

Comment: Anyone please have a look at this. At least give a little hint. Let your knowledge to be helpful for others.

Comment: You don;t need auxiliary equations or integrations to answer this question. If you were asked:  "which is a solution $x^4 - x = 78$ (A) $x = 1$ (B) $x = 3$" would you go look up Ferrari's solution for quartics, and laboriously work through it, simplifying the resultant nested radicals of complex values, until you could finally see which is among the results? No. You just plug $1$ and $3$ into the formula and check for which it holds true. In your problem, you have differential equation and are asked which of two potential solutions solves it. PLUG them in and see which makes the PDE true.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair thanks. That was an wonderful explanation. (+1)